# White space above second inline-block div

Tags: html, css

I'm sure I've overlooked something here but cannot work it out. There's white space above my second inline-block div, and this only occurs when the 'text here' length in the right div is less than that in the left.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B2S4r/2/ (You'll need to make the HTML view wider to see them along side each other)

```
<div style="border-top: 1px dashed black; display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align:right; font-size: 11px;">
        <div style="display: block; width: 80px; height: 50px; float: left; background-color: #cdcdcd; background-position: left center;">
        </div>

        <span class="main_header" style="font-size: 21px; margin: 0;">Title</span>
        <br />
        Subtitle

    </div>

    <div style="display:block; background-color: #efefef; height: 75px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
    Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here 
    </div>
</div>

<div style="border-top: 1px dashed black; display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align:right; font-size: 11px;">
        <div style="display: block; width: 80px; height: 50px; float: left; background-color: #cdcdcd; background-position: left center;">
        </div>

        <span class="main_header" style="font-size: 21px; margin: 0;">Title</span>
        <br />
        Subtitle

    </div>

    <div style="display:block; background-color: #efefef; height: 75px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
    Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text 
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: First of all I would start off with getting rid of all that inline css. It makes very difficult to see what is really going on.

Comment: Point taken. I never usually use inline css but it seemed easier to just use it until I found the right attributes, thereafter separating them.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the jsfiddle given in the question and in the answer. They both look the same.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Default value of **`vertical-align`** is `baseline` and when applied to blocks of different heights, it's often unwanted.

Applying a value of **`top`** will solve your problem. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/B2S4r/3/ (as there's no stylesheet in your fiddle but only inline CSS, I won't even try to find how to aim for the one on the right)

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a better, cleaner solution: (**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B2S4r/8/)**)

```
<div class="box">
    <hgroup>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
    </hgroup>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor
        quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.
        Aenean.</p>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        border-top:    1px dashed black;
        display:       inline-block;
        width:         250px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-right:  10px;
        margin-top:    0;
    }

    .box hgroup {
        height:         50px;
        padding-top:    2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        text-align:     right;
        font-size:      11px;
        border-left:    100px rgb(205, 205, 205) solid;
    }

    .box h2 {
        font-size:   21px;
        margin:      0;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .box h3 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .box p {
        background-color: #efefef;
        height:           75px;
        padding:          5px;
        font-size:        12px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, I've never come across the `hgroup` tag before. Wish I could accept > 1 answer, thanks.

Comment: @sooper: hgroup is an HTML5 element.

Comment: Old post but for others stumbling upon this. hgroup was removed from spec unfortunately.

http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/

Answer (score 1):

If you add `float:left` to both divs, your problem will be resolved.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="grayBox"></div>

        <span class="main_header">Title</span><br />
        Subtitle
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="grayBox"></div>

        <span class="main_header">Title</span><br />
        Subtitle
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text 
    </div>
</div>​

<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.article {
    border-top: 1px dashed black; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 250px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    margin-top: 0;
    float:left;        
}

.header {
    height: 50px; 
    padding-top: 2px; 
    padding-bottom: 2px; 
    text-align:right; 
    font-size: 11px;    
}

.main_header {
    font-size: 21px; 
    margin: 0;   
}

.grayBox {
    display: block; 
    width: 80px; 
    height: 50px; 
    float: left; 
    background-color: #cdcdcd; 
    background-position: left center;    
}

.content {
    display:block; 
    background-color: #efefef; 
    height: 75px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: 12px;
}​

.clear {
    clear:both;
}​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B2S4r/7/)

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution is adding a `float:left` to both divs...

```
<div style=" border-top: 1px dashed black; display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0; float: left;">
...
</div>
```

(and please use css ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I tried pasting html for 1st block in next one and it worked w/o problem.

```
<div style=" border-top: 1px dashed black; display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align:right; font-size: 11px;">
        <div style="display: block; width: 80px; height: 50px; float: left; background-color: #cdcdcd; background-position: left center;">
        </div>

        <span class="main_header" style="font-size: 21px; margin: 0;">Title</span>
        <br />
        Subtitle

    </div>

    <div style="display:block; background-color: #efefef; height: 75px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
    Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here
    </div>
</div>

<div style=" border-top: 1px dashed black; display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; text-align:right; font-size: 11px;">
        <div style="display: block; width: 80px; height: 50px; float: left; background-color: #cdcdcd; background-position: left center;">
        </div>

        <span class="main_header" style="font-size: 21px; margin: 0;">Title</span>
        <br />
        Subtitle

    </div>

    <div style="display:block; background-color: #efefef; height: 75px; padding: 5px; font-size: 12px;">
    Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here Text here
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/B2S4r/6/